# how to set lottie animation in java as we do in xml?

Tags: android, lottie

we do `app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/great"` to fetch lottie file but how can we do it in `java` to fetch lottie file like that as of `XML`? I tired to do many things but could not solve that. how can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the animation from the xml file can be done in 2 ways:

```
by using app:lottie_fileName=”motorcycle.json”
or app:lottie_rawRes=”@raw/motorcycle”.
```

The code equivalent of the first is this:

```
av_from_code.setAnimation("motorcycle.json")
```

Note that your animaniton file must be in  your assets folder.

Comment: there is option of .setAnimation for from assets, from raw